# Why is the differential operator $L$ not linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

A differential operator $L$ is linear if: $$L(c_1 u_1+c_2 u_2)=c_1 L(u_1)+c_2 L(u_2),$$ $$c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$u_1=u_1(\overrightarrow{x})$$
$$u_2=u_2(\overrightarrow{x})$$
Could you explain me why $$Lu=u \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_1}}+\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_2}}$$
is not linear??

Comment: Did you try to compare L(2u) and 2L(u)?

Comment: $$2L(u)=2(u \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_1}}+\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_2}})$$
$$L(2u)=2(2u \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_1}}+\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_2}})$$
So since $L(2u) \neq 2L(u)$ L is not linear..correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $L(au)$.
$$L(au)=au\frac{\partial au}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial au}{\partial x_2}=a^2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}=a\left(au\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}\right)$$
What is $aL(u)$?
$$aL(u)=au\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}\neq a\left(au\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}\right)$$
So,
$$L(au)\neq aL(u)\mbox{, so $L$ is not linear (obvious if we take $a=2$).}$$

Comment: A ok! I got it!! Thank you very much for your answer!!!

Comment: @MaryStar Sure!

Answer (score 1):

You can find many examples that breaks linearity, for instance if we take $u=x_1$ and $v=x_2$, then $L(u)=u$, $L(v)=1$ but $L(u+v)=u+v+1$.
In fact $L(f+g)=(f+g)\big(f_{x_1}+g_{x_1}\big)+\big(f_{x_2}+g_{x_2}\big)=\big(ff_{x_1}+f_{x_2}\big)+\big(gg_{x_1}+g_{x_2}\big)+\big(fg_{x_1}+gf_{x_1}\big)=L(f)+L(g)+\big(fg_{x_1}+gf_{x_1}\big)$,

Comment: Ok!! Thanks a lot!!!!